# Ms.access, importing error, database engine couldn't find the object "..."

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I'm doing is:
I have designed  a form in order to importing data to my tables from excel. 
I've made a vba code on a command botton click event, which allows user to select their `.xls` file with `filedialog` method, and after clicking import, The VBA code is :
 `cbotablename` is the table that user selects to import data into it:

```
i = forms![frm_import-export]![cbotablename]
Strsql = "delete " & i & " .* from" & i
Docmd.RunSQL  strsql
```

This code works normaly
After deleting old data I wanna import the new data by this code :

```
Docmd.transferspreadsheet acimport, 10, i , 
selected item, true
```

And I get this error:
    Microsoft database engine could not find the 
   object `tblname`. Make sure the object exists!!

But all tables are exitst.

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- check that your variables have the values you expect. What is `selected item` supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks Andre -- Yes I've checked the variables, they have values. SelectedItem is the file that users selected to import.

Comment: Please show your real code. As listed, it won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this problem. 
I've used a linked table which is being updated by an Excel file selected by users, a delete query and an append query.
So when users click on the import button, VBA code relinks the linked table to excel file and then runs delete query to remove previous data from main table and then runs the append query to import new data from linked table to main table. 
As a result, I don't need those linked excel files and I'll be able to transfer database wherever i want.